# AudioKit AKFFTTap does not fill fftData array above bin 512

Tags: swift, buffer, fft, audiokit

I want to increase the FFT resolution and have more bins per signal analysed.
When i leave the fftSize and all buffer lengths at default in AKSettings i get a 512 bin fft, the fftData array has all of the 512 array elements filled out.

From this I am able to get real and imag parts, magnitudes and it works.

If i setup the ffttap with a higher fftsize like so
`fftTap = AKFFTTap.init(mic, fftSize: .huge)`

I get an increased fftData array size, the fftData.count is 1024, but only 512 array elements are filled, everything past fftData[511] are 0.0s.

Am I missing some specific configuration step when I want to increase the FFT resolution?

Anybody with some input would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a bug you could file with AudioKit. Create a simple test that shows the expected behavior (a filled 1024 element array) not being filled, and create a PR based off the the "develop" branch of AudioKit. This PR will not pass continuous integration until the problem is fixed by someone.